# ansible.cfg file hijack my django project log file output path

Tags: django, logging, ansible

I have a strange django log file output problem, I use the ansible 2.5.0 module in my django 1.11.11 project like this `from ansible.plugins.callback import CallbackBase`, and the `log_path` setting in the `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg` file actually takes effect for my django project log file output, like a hijack:

```
# /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg file
# logging is off by default unless this path is defined
# if so defined, consider logrotate
log_path = /var/log/ansible.log
```

All my django log output to the `/var/log/ansible.log` which is quite odd

```
# /var/log/ansible.log
2019-01-07 17:49:22,271 django.server "GET /docs/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1391207
2019-01-07 17:49:23,262 django.server "GET /docs/schema.js HTTP/1.1" 200 111440
```

I did set up the LOGGING in my django settings, the django setting takes effect too, and the output is like this:

```
# /var/log/django_debug.log
"GET /docs/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1391207
"GET /docs/schema.js HTTP/1.1" 200 111440
```

It will be two log files for the same django project in same log level I defined in the django settings:

```
# django settings.py
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '/var/log/django_debug.log',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you import Ansible as a Python module by any chance?

**TLDR**: When you import Ansible as a module, the logger instance inside Ansible lib gets instantiated first and you end up using Ansible's logger, unless you set `disable_existing_loggers` to `True`.

**Why this happens?**

Python logging is a singleton, which means that only one object of logger can exist in the memory in given process.

Libraries (such as Ansible) can also use loggers internally. In my case, the Ansible's logger was instantiated somewhere in the Ansible global scope. https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/utils/display.py#L65

When you import library, the logger is already instantiated, so your own logger will inherit the existing log handler and you'll end up writing logs to both log files.

**What to do to prevent this?**

Please try switching the `disable_existing_loggers` setting to `True`.

Django docs for logging: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/logging/#configuring-logging

Analogical settings for Python logger itself: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html?highlight=disable_existing_loggers#logging.config.fileConfig

One note for my case: I used `logging.handlers.WatchedFileHandler` which seems to inherit previous loggers by default.

Please give feedback if this fixed your problem!

Comment: yes, i import ansible as python module. and `disable_existing_loggers setting to True`. works. thanks